# Looking for a Teen Wolf Sterek Fic

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, teen-wolf

I'm looking for a [Sterek](https://archiveofourown.org/tags/Derek%20Hale*s*Stiles%20Stilinski/works) fic I read on AO3. I remember that Derek was an alpha and that Stiles became friends with Erica, Boyd, and Isaac before they started being turned into werewolves by Derek and leaving him out of things, then Stiles finds out about werewolves and they stop avoiding him. Stiles's best friend was Erica, not Scott, and the Hale family was still alive, I think. The last thing I remember reading was that Stiles and Derek had a fight and Erica, Boyd, and Isaac came over to Stiles's house to watch movies and find out what happened between Derek and Stiles.

Comment: Can you think of any more details? https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fan-fiction-story-id-question?noredirect=1&lq=1 has some prompts to help.

Comment: I remember that Stiles meet Isaac when he some how helped him get away from his abusive father and Erica at a party when she had a seizure and he helped her I can't remember anything else Sorry.